# Are two capacitors connected together considered to be parallel or series?

Tags: capacitor, capacitance, parallel, series, energy

If both ends of two capacitors are connected to each other but in such a way that the positive end of one capacitor is connected to the negative end of another capacitor, do we say that the capacitors are connected in series rather than in parallel?

The question might be really silly but in my college solution: The equivalent capacitance of a two parallel capacitors connected like that is calculated in such a way as if they are in series. I have attached the picture of the question. Here the equivalent capacitance after the switch is closed should be parallel as both ends get connected to each other but it was so not done.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This question is talking about the stored energy, charge and voltage.

Considering the capacitors individually, the initial energy on each cap is \$V \times V \times C/2\$.
Substituting gives \$100 \times 100 \times 0.00001 \times 0.5=0.05~\mathrm{J}\$.

So total energy stored in the 2 caps is 0.1 J.

Given that they are opposite polarity, once the switch is closed, the charge on one with exactly cancel out the charge on the other, meaning eventual situation is 0 V on each, and 0 J stored.

The energy will have been dissipated in resistive heating in the wires and switch arc during the equalization. Initial currents might be very large.

Comment: Thank you for explaining what the question meant with the clarification on Energy.

Comment: (A very small part of the energy will have been radiated over quite broad a range of frequencies.)

Comment: To be 100% accurate, there may also be some energy lost as sound from the spark, and chemical energy tied up with reactions at the contact surface.

Answer (score 3):

Two capacitors connected positive to negative, negative to positive are connected in a loop. Whether they are considered parallel or series depends on how other circuit elements are connected to them. The polarity doesn't matter. That the diagram has a switch between them would make them in series with each other and the switch. If you put the switch from end to end they'd be in parallel with each other and the switch.

Comment: Hence bottom-line, if the solution says: "After the switch is closed, capacitors are in series, hence Equivalent Capacitance = C/2", this will be a wrong statement.

Comment: @RKEshat After the switch is closed they are essentially in parallel, because in a question like this the switch is assumed to have no resistance. The question really doesn't have anything to do with calculating parallel or series capacitance, it has to do with the charge on the capacitors and what happens to it when the switch is closed.

Answer (score 2):

I would say there is no way to say if it is parallel or series, unless you decide what is the circuit "around" those capacitors. If you consider the rest of the circuit to be the switch, then from the point of view of the switch, they are in series. If you consider the bottom wire to be ground, a supply coming from the top left, and a load connected to the top right, then they are in parallel.

Anyhow, if you have polarized capacitors as drawn, there is not much sens in asking yourself if they are in series or in parallel, as they will be destroyed as soon as you connect them. I would strongly recommend NOT to try this in real life : at best you destroy the capacitors, at worse they migh ignite/explode.

Comment: So what happened here is that total energy before the switch is closed is 5 mJ and after the switch is closed is 0 J, does that 0V represent the fact that the capacitors are destroyed and hence no charge is stored in between the plates for which there is no energy present? @Sandro

Comment: I believe the first time you wrote "parallel" you actually meant "series".

Comment: well, the 0V represent the fact that the capacitor are discharged. All the energy was dissipated in heat (which is probably too much for the capacitors, causing them to fail). If you charged them to 100mV instead of 100V, they would probably just heat up instead of being destroyed

Comment: @BenVoigt and @ evildemonic : your are righ : I corrected my type

Comment: Last paragraph is mostly correct, but the cap that's going to fail will do so even before being connected into the circuit.  Merely charging it in reverse polarity to the initial conditions will kill it.

Comment: I assumed the 100V on each cap was an absolute voltage, ie in the direction not distroying the cap. So initial condition will be fine.